# In RSpec/Rails acceptance tests,is there any way to push messages to the RSpec output and maintain the nice indentation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

My acceptance tests (RSpec/Capybara) have some long sequences of steps all under a single `it...do` block, and I'd like to manually add some additional documentation of each step into the RSpec documentation output.

So where the RSpec output (in documentation format) currently looks like:

```
FooController
  New user creates account and creates profile
    it passes
```

Within the long sequence of steps I'd like to push some additional info to the output:

```
FooController
  New user creates account and creates profile
    ... new user saw signup page!
    ... new user got email confirmation!
    ... confirmation link worked!
    ... new user saw empty profile!
    ... new user filled in profile
    it passes
```

In terms of documenting the app, those extra statements would be better than a large black box with a single 'it passed' result message.

Since there is apparently no way to use multiple `it...do` blocks to build the long sequence of steps for a acceptance test, I'm hoping there is a simple way to push additional messages to the RSpec output stream, ideally with them being indented and displayed (red/green) as if they were pat or separate `it...do` examples.

Comment: In shoulda you could achieve it with this workaround: https://github.com/lifo/fast_context but I'm affraid it's not possible in rspec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did... added a nextstep("message") method to my specs that outputs "message" to the console using awesome_print gem so I can color it, and also to the logger.

```
  def nextstep(txt)
    $step += 1
    @speclog.debug ''
    @speclog.debug ''
    @speclog.debug "#{$scene}, step: #{$step}: " + txt
    ap (' ' * ($indent * 2 - 1)) + "step: #{$step}: " + txt, {:color => {:string => :blueish}}
  end
```

A little hackish, but it does give us very nice descriptive output when running rspec, for example if we have

```
it "New user creates account and creates profile" do
   # some assertions
   nextstep "... new user saw signup page!"
   # some assertions
   nextstep " ... new user got email confirmation!"
   # some assertions
   nextstep " ... confirmation link worked!"
   # some assertions
   nextstep "... new user saw empty profile!"
   # some assertions
   nextstep "... new user filled in profile"
end
```

we get the more descriptive spec output as shown in the question (and if there's a failure we see the step we were on):

```
   step 1: ... new user saw signup page!
   step 2: ... new user got email confirmation!
   step 3: ... confirmation link worked!
   step 4: ... new user saw empty profile!
   step 5: ... new user filled in profile"
```

Comment: This seems a nice solution, but I cannot understand where the crucial `$indent` variable comes from.

Comment: oh - in my specs I have a $indent variable that lets me control teh indenting so sub-sub-test outputs can be indented deeper

Answer (score 1):

Eventually, I opted for customization of the [DocumentationFormatter](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/master/lib/rspec/core/formatters/documentation_formatter.rb), by including the following code somewhere in the `spec/support` folder (to ensure automatic loading):

```
require "rspec/core/formatters/documentation_formatter"

class RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup
  def step(msg)
    example.metadata[:step_messages] << msg if example.metadata[:step_messages]
    yield
  end
end

class RSpec::Core::Formatters::DocumentationFormatter
  def example_started(example)
    example.metadata[:step_messages] = []
  end

  def example_passed(example)
    output.puts passed_output(example)
    print_steps(example)
  end

  private
    def print_steps(example)
      example.metadata[:step_messages].each do |msg|
      output.puts detail_color("#{'  ' * (@group_level + 1)}#{msg}")
    end
  end
end
```

With this trick, you obtain a `step` method that you can use within your `it` blocks.
When running rspec with `--format documentation`, relevant messages from `step` blocks will be printed out, appropriately indented.
For instance, the following code

```
it "should show all and only appoved posts" do
  step "show all approved posts" do
    Post.all.approved.each do |post|
      should have_content(post.title)
    end
  end
  step "show only approved posts" do
    should have_selector(".post", count: Post.all.approved.count)
  end
end
```

will produce the following output (with step strings colorized in light blue):

```
should show all and only appoved posts
  show all approved posts
  show only approved posts
```

This is admittedly a very rough solution, but it can probably be made nicer with a little bit more work.

Comment: that's a pretty neat solution... if you have rspec randomizing the orders of tests (eg, not using defaultorder) will the "steps" still execute in the order specified in the spec?

Comment: Good question! Actually, I do not know, as I normally do not randomize order with the documentation formatter.